# SQL Server stored procedure not able concat varchar at input parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I trying to insert data from a database into multiple reports. I would like to made the destination file name to be dynamic, which was a variable. But when I replace the file name with variable, I get a syntax error.

```
insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\Report\PeopleCounter\myDynamicFileName.xlsx;',
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
    select * from myresult;
```

[image]

What would be the easy way to fix this?

Comment: Be aware the T-SQL is a very crufty language. If the [syntax diagram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql#syntax) only shows a literal string as a possibility, that usually means that only a literal string is allowed. Not variables. Not *expressions*. Indeed, the remarks lower on that page state it doesn't accept variables.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dynamic query

```
DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @value = 'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\Report\PeopleCounter\myDynamicFileName.xlsx;'

DECLARE @a NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @a = 'insert into OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'', 
''' + @value + ''',
''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'')
    select * from myresult;'

PRINT @a
EXEC @a
```

Print @a result:

```
    insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
    'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\Report\PeopleCounter\myDynamicFileName.xlsx;',
    'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
     select * from myresult;
```